# How to multiply Doubles without losing precision?

Tags: kotlin, double, precision

Given this function:

```
fun  multiplyByHundred(num:Double):Double{
    return num * 100
}
```

These are results for some inputs:

69.56 => 6956.0

69.57 => 6956.999999999999

69.58 => 6958.0

69.59 => 6959.0

1. Why does 69.57 result in 6956.999999999999?
2. How do I correctly do this calculation without losing precision and make it work with any Double?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't. A `double` can represent only a sparse subset of the real numbers. You might get away with using a `double` if you can format the output appropriately (which is essentially what Microsoft Excel does, along with some very clever tricks for expressions like 1/3 + 1/3 + 1/3).

If you need perfect precision then use a type capable of doing that. The decimal type `BigDecimal` is probably what you want.

If you're working with money, and don't need to worry about currencies that have 1000s (e.g. Tunisian Dinar) or bitcoin (8 decimal places), then working in cents and using integers is one approach.

Comment: Consider:  https://www.exploringbinary.com/decimal-precision-of-binary-floating-point-numbers/

Comment: This is actually a case where I'm trying to convert a currency to cents

Comment: @kev one thing I’ve heard time and again is that when dealing with money you generally shouldn’t use floating point numbers.